# General Number Field Sieve Background Knowledge

Tags: number-theory

I was looking the other day the concepts of GNFS [here](https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/36618/etd.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) which i found very interesting but I couldn't follow the paper. For example I found a reference to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and i understood that I should probably start from some basics and then come back.

How would you suggest to proceed in order to understand this paper?

I know that the example I specified will be included in an abstract algebra book. I have also studied some concepts of number theory. No formal mathematical background.

Any other resources that I should be equipped with for this task?

Comment: The quadratic sieve should be understandable without a lot of background (you should clarify if you have gotten this far), it's discussed in chapter 1 of your link and also I think the explanation on Wikipedia is good. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve

Comment: You might also be interested to learn about algebraic number theory, in particular rings of integers, factorization of ideals into primes, and the concept of norms of ideals. As an (imprecise, perhaps not completely accurate) attempt at an overview: GNFS tries to find factorizations of certain ideals of "small" norm in number fields to collect relations in a similar way as in the quadratic sieve. It then finds perfect squares that map homomorphically to perfect squares in Z/nZ.

Comment: Gerry Myerson left a pretty good Comment addressing the required background knowledge in [this earlier Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287646/simply-explain-the-general-number-field-sieve#comment627655_287646).